# Possibility of getting a UK tourist visa, doing postgraduate, travelling with parents who have alreay the visa and supported by father

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am planning to go to UK and france this summer with my parents for family visit. My parents have uk visa already but mine got expired. I already have the visa for EU countries. I am planning to apply for UK visit visa on base of sponsor from my sister. My scenario is that i am currently studying in my home country and also doing part time work. My father is retired but is financially sound and he is supporting for my trip expenses i.e tickets. I am applying as student (non working) and applying as dependent upon father. Also i have previous refusal as well from us one for visit visa and one for study visa. However, i have visited uk and eu countries couple of time before for family visit.

I want to know what are chance of my case, i will attached bank statements, tax return and covering letter from my father that he will support me during my visit.

Answer (score 3):

We cannot predict your **chances**. Whe have no idea what the UK has on file for you.

- You should include *your* bank statements to document your current lifestyle, and *your father's* bank statements to document the source of your funds.
- Mention that you already have a Schengen visa when you explain the premise of your trip.
- Mention that you have been denied visa before where that is asked.

With that, you can hope for the best. The previous visits will count in your favor.

---

**Clarification:**

You show **your own bank statements** to demonstrate that you have regular income (from your part-time work, perhaps regular payments from your father) and regular expenses (paying rent if you do not live at home, tuition fees, books, and so on). It is important that the numbers make sense for a student. No unexplained big deposits, no unexplained big withdrawals, just normal living month to month. This supports your claim that you are a student *now* and that you will be a student *in the future*.

You show **your father's bank statements** to demonstrate that he can afford to pay a tourist trip for you.

There are many parts of the world where families pool their money to send one young man to enter Europe illegally and to work. These young men are expected to send money home to repay that investment.

Your father's bank statements show that he has enough money to give you the trip as a gift and not as a loan.

Comment: Should i apply on basis of student or show my part time work also, if i apply as a student then is it necessary to show my bank statement or father statement is enough.

Comment: The answer says "you should include **your** bank statements". You should tell them about both your studies and your work.

Comment: @zohaibanwar, see the clarification above.

Comment: @zohaibanwar, I don't know if 2,000 pounds is enough to mention, perhaps one of the other people can answer that.